# How to normalize vector to [0 10] range

Tags: python, math

Hi I have a vector where the min is 5.748113263784852 and the max is 175.5
I want to scale those values to a 0 to 10 ( 1 2 3 ... 10 ). 
how can I do?

Comment: Subtract by the minimum and divide by the maximum. Then multiply by 10 and round.

Comment: Do you want that scale 0 to 10 (0, 1, ..., 10) or 1 to 10 (1, 2, ..., 10)?

Comment: @NilsWerner: Perhaps you should clarify that the OP is to divide by the *new* maximum, the value that is greatest after he has subtracted the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:
first deduct the minimum value from each element
then, find the maximum value of the resulting vector.
finally, divide each value of the resulting vector, and multiply by 10

```
def normalize_zero_to_ten(vector):
    """assumes all values of vector are positive
    """
    mini = min(vector)
    vec = [elt-mini for elt in vector]
    correction = 1 / (max(vec) * 10)   
    # elt * correction is equivalent to divide by max and multiply by 10
    return [elt * correction for elt in vec]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    v = [5.5, 26, 175, 32]
    print(normalize_zero_to_ten(v))
```

#### output:

```
[0.0, 1.2094395280235988, 10.0, 1.5634218289085546]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thought would be to normalize the vector first by dividing every element by the square root of the sum of squares of all values:

```
magnitude = sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i]))
normalized = v[i]/magnitude
```

This gives you a vector with magnitude equal to 1.0, with every component in the range [-1, 1]

It should be easy to translate and scale as needed once you have the normalized vector.

It's a more mathematical, less ad hoc approach to the problem.